# Thread safe singleton implementation in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns

The following is a well known implementation of singleton pattern in C++.
However, I'm not entirely sure whether its thread-safe.
Based upon answers to similar question asked here previously, it seems it is thread safe.
Is that so?

```
//Curiously Recurring Template Pattern    
//Separates a class from its Singleton-ness (almost).    
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

template<class T> class Singleton {
  Singleton(const Singleton&);
  Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&);
protected:
  Singleton() {}
  virtual ~Singleton() {}
public:
  static T& instance() {
    static T theInstance;
    return theInstance;
  }
};

// A sample class to be made into a Singleton
class MyClass : public Singleton<MyClass> {
 int x;
protected:
  friend class Singleton<MyClass>;
  MyClass() { x = 0; }
public:
 void setValue(int n) { x = n; }
  int getValue() const { return x; }
};
```

Comment: Why did you make this a WIKI?  It's a completely valid question.

Comment: you didn't give any reasons why *you* think the pattern implementation isn't thread safe. Please do.

Comment: what is the aim of the friend class here? can someone answer?

Comment: Oh shoot! Should have checked faqs to see what it means, rather than assuming it to be something.

Comment: @Ankur I think you can edit your question and uncheck community WIKI.

Comment: @Jared, Edit doesn't has any option to uncheck Wiki :(

Comment: @Ahmed. It is there for the statement, "static T theInstance" to compile. As you might see, MyClass has protected constructor so we need the friend specifier so that Singleton class (Singleton<MyClass>, to be precise) can declare a local static of type MyClass.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, this is not thread safe because the static local is not guarded in any way.  By default a static local is not thread safe.  This means you could run into the following issues

- Constructor for the singleton runs more than once
- The assignment to the static is not guaranteed to be atomic hence you could see a partial assignment in multi-threaded scenarios
- Probably a few more that I'm missing.

Here is a detailed blog entry by Raymond Chen on why C++ statics are not thread safe by default.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/08/85901.aspx

Comment: so basically this means that it is not possible to do a OS agnostic singleton using C++ ? i.e. you always need some critical section or similar to do one?

Answer (score 1):

IT IS **NOT** THREAD SAFE.
To become thread safe you should add a check before the lock (semaphore lock) and an other check after the lock. And then you are sure that even in simultaneous call from different threads you provide one instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not threadsafe, unless you configure your compiler to generate threadsafe code for static accesses.

However, it's better that the code be self contained, so I'd add a mutex here and there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still interest on this topic and if you're using a **C++ 11 standard compiler** you can find [here](http://silviuardelean.ro/2012/06/05/few-singleton-approaches/) a proposal of the singleton pattern in a multithreaded environment.